# Prevent Python for loop from breaking if Google API limit reached

Tags: python

I currently have a python script that has a for loop that is triggered by an entry into my MongoDb databased. The script does some calculations before printing the results to a Google Sheet. The loop could be triggered every hour or in some cases, several times per second. This issue I'm facing is that the Google API has usage limits that are occasionally being exceeded and thus breaking the loop.

What I want to do, is use some code that will attempt to print the results to Google Sheets using Google's API but if there's a usage limit, sleep for 2 minutes before resuming, instead of breaking the loop because of the error.

Can anyone recommend where to start?

Comment: "*Can anyone recommend where to start?*" Questions phrased like this, especially when presented without any accompanying code (contrary to the requirements of [ask]) are much too broad for Stack Overflow's Q&A format. For starters, Google should be returning a `429 Too Many Requests` status code, which you should be able to look for within your code and perform the "*sleep*" you describe before continuing.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the requirements for asking. I was however just looking for somewhere to start and don't really have any code that would further my question. The try/except method that someone has kindly answered was exactly what I needed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would use `try` to save to sheet and `except` to sleep 2 mins then save to sheet